# Django: Cache function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created the following serializer where I call the function `_calculate_image_dimensions` twice. I now tried @cachedproperty but doesn't work because I have to pass the values `width, height`. However, they will not change for get_width and get_height. Is there a way to make sure the calculation only computes once?

```
class IntegrationImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    width = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    height = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = IntegrationImage
        fields = ("image", "width", "height")

    def _calculate_image_dimensions(self, width, height) -> int:
        MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 350
        aspect_ratio = width / height
        if width > height:
            width = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE
            height = width / aspect_ratio
        else:
            height = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE
            width = height * aspect_ratio
        return round(width), round(height)

    def get_width(self, obj: IntegrationImage) -> int:
        width, height = self._calculate_image_dimensions(
            obj.image.width, obj.image.height
        )
        return width

    def get_height(self, obj: IntegrationImage) -> int:
        width, height = self._calculate_image_dimensions(
            obj.image.width, obj.image.height
        )
        return height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially it seems a bit confusing to me, having a method `get_width` executing a function to get width **and** height and then return `width`  only.

Does it make sense to slightly change the API structure by using `dimensions` field (which might not be actually efficient if `width` and `height` are referred to a lot of places)?
If it doesn't require you to change a lot of references to `width` and `height` this would call `_calculate_image_dimensions` only once (which i belive is the problem you are trying to solve?) and you won't need caching.

```py
class IntegrationImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dimensions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = IntegrationImage
        fields = ("image", "dimensions")

    def _calculate_image_dimensions(self, width, height) -> int:
        MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 350
        aspect_ratio = width / height
        if width > height:
            width = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE
            height = width / aspect_ratio
        else:
            height = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE
            width = height * aspect_ratio
        return round(width), round(height)

    def get_dimensions(self, obj: IntegrationImage) -> int:
        width, height = self._calculate_image_dimensions(
            obj.image.width, obj.image.height
        )
        return {"width": width, "height": height}
```

Comment: Good idea. Looks much better :)

Answer (score 1):

Make it a free function (outside the class) and decorate it with `lru_cache()`:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def calculate_image_dimensions(width, height) -> int:
    MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 350
    aspect_ratio = width / height
    if width > height:
        width = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE
        height = width / aspect_ratio
    else:
        height = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE
        width = height * aspect_ratio
    return round(width), round(height)
```

This will cache the results for the lifetime of the worker process.

(However, I doubt a function with a couple comparisons and divisions is the performance bottleneck in your app.)